# How can I use Swiper in Polymer?

Tags: plugins, polymer, swiper.js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../swiper/swiper-3.4.2.min.css">
<script src="../swiper/swiper-3.4.2.min.js"></script>

 <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide aa">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

It does not work.

Comment: Welcome to "SO" please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your and the communities user experience.

Comment: Make a fiddle and tell us where you got stuck. The above doesn't look like polymer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/safetychanger/iron-swiper) component made for Polymer which wraps around Swiper.js